# PATCH Ajax request in Laravel

Tags: ajax, rest, laravel, http-verbs

Is it possible to make Ajax PATCH requests to Laravel, or am I restricted to POST? Laravel uses PATCH in input hidden fields. However, I am not using form elements—just buttons that should partially update a record when clicked (via an Ajax request).

How would the route look like for this?

**Routes file**

`Route::patch('questions/{id}', 'QuestionController@update')->before('admin');`

I am not sure if Laravel routes support PATCH.

**Controller**

```
public function update($id) {
    if (Request::ajax() && Request::isMethod('patch')) {
        //partially update record here
    }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```js
$('div#question_preview <some button selector>').click(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'questions/' + question_id,
        type: 'PATCH',
        data: {status: 'some status'}
    });
});
```

Comment: @SetKyarWaLar PUT is used if you know the entire contents of the resource.  In my case, I am only updating a part of the resource without the entire resource data which is what patch is for.

Comment: Can you describe your view in your question? @Rafael

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible. Try in your JavaScript:

```
$('#div#question_preview <some button selector>').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'questions/'+question_id,
        type: 'PATCH',
        data: {status: <SOME VALUE I WANT>, _method: "PATCH"},
        success: function(res) {
        }
    });
});
```

In your route:

```
Route::patch('questions/{id}', 'QuestionController@update')->before('admin');
```

In your QuestionController Controller's update method:

```
dd(Request::method());
```

You will see the response like

```
string(5) "PATCH"
```

Read more about request information in the [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#request-information).

Comment: :D Thank you man, you are awesome! Also I did not include the `_method: "PATCH"` in my data since it is already being requested as patch and it worked without any issues.  Thank you for your help, cheers!

Comment: Quick question but how do I access the status values (in my data) on the server side? Usually I would use $_GET or $_POST supers but for patch?

Comment: For Laravel `Request::isMethod('PATCH')` ?

Comment: I mean to access my data in the ajax call? I want to access the key / value pair I stored in the jQuery data method.

Comment: `Input::all()` for all of your input values. For specific name `Input::get('specific-name');` Read more on [doc](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#basic-input)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible!

You should need to provide an extra parameter in the form request called as `_method` with a value `PATCH`.

JS

```js
$('div#question_preview <some button selector>').click(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'questions/'+question_id,
        type: 'PATCH',
        data: {status: 'some status',_method: 'PATCH'}
    });
});
```

You can provide a hidden input in the view file with the value `PATCH` for better readability
HTML

```html
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
```

If you are using `FormData`, you need to send the request as `POST`. The Laravel application will automatically get it as a `PATCH` request because you included @method('PATCH'). So your route and method for that will get triggered.

JS with FormData

```js
$('div#question_preview <some button selector>').click(function (event) {
    let form_data= new FormData();
    form_data.append('status','some status');
    form_data.append('_method','PATCH');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'questions/'+question_id,
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data
    });
});
```