# Update image via jquery in laravel 10

Tags: jquery, laravel, image, patch

I am trying to update profile image in Laravel using Jquery.

What is wrong here? I want to update profile image via `Jquery` patch call, can you help me?

This is my JS file

```
$("#image").on('change', function (e) {
    const origin = window.location.origin;
    const file = e.target.files[0];

    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('image', file);
    formData.append('_method', 'patch');

    $.ajax({
        url: `${origin}/profile/profile-pic/`,
        type: 'PATCH',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content,
            'Accept': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log('Image uploaded successfully');
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            // Request failed, handle the error
            console.log('Error: ' + error);
        }
    });
});
```

This is my controller

```
public function updateImage(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    dd($request->all());
    return response()->json();
}
```

`dd()` is empty array, how can I resolve this?

Comment: Looking at other similar questions I see `Route::patch` and `Request::isMethod('PATCH')` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914559/patch-ajax-request-in-laravel

Comment: [check more here](https://www.google.com/search?q=laravel+jquery+method+patch+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

I would try this way:

```
$("#image").on('change', function (e) {
const origin = window.location.origin;
const file = e.target.files[0];
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', file);
formData.append('_method', 'patch');
$.ajax({
    url: `${origin}/profile/profile-pic/`,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content,
        'Accept': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log('Image uploaded successfully');
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        // Request failed, handle the error
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

});

Ajax only accepts methods **GET** or **POST**.